# Proving that a map is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I am trying assignments in topology and I got stuck on this question:

> Prove that the map $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ defined by
>   $$f(x, y) = y^3 + xy^2 + x + y$$
>   is a quotient map.

I have done a course on topology but quotient maps were not covered in it. So, I am unable to do it.

I am using this definition of quotient map: A map $p$ is called a quotient map if $p: X\to Y$ is such that
(a) $p$ is surjective,
(b) $p$ is continuous,
(c) $U$ belonging to $Y$, $p^{-1}(U)$ open in $X$ implies $U$ is open in $Y$.

For my function, the first 2 conditions are satisfied but I am not able to prove that it satisfies the 3rd condition.

Kindly tell.

Comment: I haven't worked this idea through, but for the condition (c) I think you can try to prove the contrapositive: if $U$ is a subset of $Y$ which is not open, then $p^{-1}(U)$ is not open either. I feel like there should be a more clever way of proving this condition, but right now I can't find it

Comment: A continuous surjection that is open (or closed) is a quotient map. [This is a _sufficient_ but not necessary condition, there are quotient maps that are neither open nor closed.] Try showing that $f$ is open in 2.(b).

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you please give a hint for proving it open?

Comment: If a function $g \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, is differentiable, then $g$ is open at all points where the derivative $Dg$ is surjective. (Looking up the implicit function theorem and/or the inverse function theorem can help if you don't remember how that goes.) Here we have $m = 1$, so the surjectivity of $Df$ is equivalent to the non-vanishing of the gradient of $f$.

Comment: @OP what is the context of this exercise? Are you supposed to work with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the final topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}} = \mathcal{T}_1$ denote the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now consider the final topology on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by $f$, i.e. $$\mathcal{T}_2 = \{V \subset \mathbb{R} \mid f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{T}_{1}\}.$$

Now by construction, $f$ is obviously $\mathcal{T}_1-\mathcal{T}_2$ continous. Since you've already proven $f$ to be surjective it follows that $f$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Is it not true with the standard topology on $\mathbb R$? This seems to trivialize the problem.

Comment: I haven't checked whether the given map is a quotient map on the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. I do not see any indication that this has to be proven explicitly for the standard topology. Usually questions like these always explicitly mention the given topologies. However, since the final topology is the finest topology on $ \mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ is continous and quotient maps usually appear in the context of quotient spaces, i found this approach most natural. Note that (c) is exactly the condition the final topology satisfies.

Comment: Hm, I disagree, I think usually people are interested in $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, and ask questions on top of it. I agree that the context of the question would clear this up though. 
It seems to be true with the usual topologies, looking at the gradient of $f$.